# BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is) fails on some image in Download folder

Tags: android, cordova, bitmap

I'm using PhoneGap 2.5.0 and here is how I call the method:

```
try {
        InputStream is = cordova.getActivity().getContentResolver()
                .openInputStream(Uri.parse(inputString));
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        is.close();
```

The code works fine when I take a photo using the camera but randomly fails on some images from the Download folder. I checked those images, they are all downloaded locally with a URL like content://media/external/images/media/xxxx. Some files are pretty large 6MB while others are small 700K. The failure just seems to be random by returning null and not caught by exception.

Answer (score 3):

From the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeStream%28java.io.InputStream%29):

> Decode an input stream into a bitmap. If the input stream is null, or cannot be used to decode a bitmap, the function returns null. The stream's position will be where ever it was after the encoded data was read.

So either your InputStream is null, or the file you are opening cannot be used to decode a Bitmap.

Answer (score 3):

Any chance it's a jpeg?

See this known issue:-

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6066

I use the following for decoding bitmaps:-

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FlushedInputStream(is), null, opts);

public class FlushedInputStream extends FilterInputStream {
public FlushedInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
    super(inputStream);
}

@Override
public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
    long totalBytesSkipped = 0L;
    while (totalBytesSkipped < n) {
        long bytesSkipped = in.skip(n - totalBytesSkipped);
        if (bytesSkipped == 0L) {
              int myByte = read();
              if (myByte < 0) {
                  break;  // we reached EOF
              } else {
                  bytesSkipped = 1; // we read one byte
              }
       }
        totalBytesSkipped += bytesSkipped;
    }
    return totalBytesSkipped;
}
}
```

Also, if some of the images are large, you may want to set the sample size so you don't cause a too large allocation.

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inSampleSize = sampleSize;
```

Where sampleSize is a sensible value you've calculated.

Comment: Yes. The images are mostly jpg files. I used the FlushedInputStream but seems to suffer from the same issue.