# Can not open image from sdcard, BitmapFactory.decodeStream returns null

Tags: android, image

I receive images from server which grabed from linkedin page. Most of them I can not decode via `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` -- it returns `null`

For this images logcat shows this row  `android decoder->decode returned false`

They successfully opend via gmail app or some gallery apps so it is posible to show them. Images are jpeg and pngs.

I have found the bug related to [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6066) and a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15840172/bitmapfactory-decodestreamis-fails-on-some-image-in-download-folder) to fix it but it is for web srteam -- in my case files on sdcard

Can you tell me please what is a possible reasons for this issue? What else I can try?

Comment: post the code you had written

Answer (score 0):

Was a problem on the server side -- byte array was converted to file, it had been replaced to image all started work as expected